# Measure thread contention on particular monitor

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, jconsole, jvisualvm

I'm considering switching from `synchronized` to a `ReadWriteLock`. Before doing it, I would like to check if it's worth it.

`ThreadMXBean` and `ThreadInfo` provide information about overall thread blocked count and time. Those blocks can be caused by multiple monitors. Is there a way to measure block statistics given a particular monitor object?

Comment: thanks a lot, I was only familiar with jconsole and visualvm and they don't provide lock contention info. jmc looks just like what I want. Could you post your answer below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jmc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html), [yourkit](https://www.yourkit.com/java/profiler/) and [jprofiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) all provide lock contention profiling.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible using [JVMTI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html).

What is you need is to write a native agent that handles a pair of events:

- [MonitorContendedEnter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#MonitorContendedEnter) - fired when a thread is about to enter syncrhonized block already acquired by another thread;
- [MonitorContendedEntered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#MonitorContendedEntered) - fired when a thread successfully acquires monitor after waiting.

Both events accept `jthread` and `jobject` arguments that correspond to a thread acquiring the monitor and the monitor object itself.

---

[Here is](https://gist.github.com/apangin/d9cdf0ae98309291b494a7c9f3954a29) a sample code for the contention profiler agent.

Answer (score 1):

Internal kernel of ReentrantReadWriteLock - private field 'sync' of type AbstractQueuedSynchronizer (AQS). 
AQS - one of greatest 'synchronizers' of Doug Lea. It contains single-linked list of contended Threads. Every Thread marked is it 'exclusive' or 'shared'.
Read for more info ["The java.util.concurrent Synchronizer Framework"](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/aqs.pdf).

You can periodically examine blocked thread queue (100 times in second) and collect stats.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class App {
    static final AtomicInteger freeTime = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static final AtomicInteger fullTime = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static final AtomicInteger readersLength = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static final AtomicInteger writersLength = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static float contended() {
        return fullTime.get() / (fullTime.get() + freeTime.get());
    }

    public static float uncontended() {
        return freeTime.get() / (fullTime.get() + freeTime.get());
    }

    public static float meanReadersQueue() {
        return readersLength.get() / fullTime.get();
    }

    public static float meanWritersQueue() {
        return writersLength.get() / fullTime.get();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
        AbstractQueuedSynchronizer sync =
                useReflection(lock, "sync", AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.class);

        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            int queueLength = sync.getQueueLength();
            if (queueLength == 0) {
                freeTime.incrementAndGet();
            } else {
                fullTime.incrementAndGet();
                int readersCount = sync.getSharedQueuedThreads().size();
                readersLength.addAndGet(readersCount);
                int writersCount = sync.getExclusiveQueuedThreads().size();
                writersLength.addAndGet(writersCount);
            }
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private static <T> T useReflection(Object from, String name, Class<T> to) throws Exception {
        Field f = from.getClass().getDeclaredField(name);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        return (T) f.get(from);
    }
}
```

Comment: how does it answer my question?

Comment: You can periodically examine blocked thread queue (100 times in second) and collect stats.

Comment: In my question, I explained that I don't want to switch before I make sure that it is worth it.